# Sails + Vue using external libraries

Tags: vue.js, sails.js

I have downloaded the Sails + VueJs framework sample code from this git repository https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration

But found I am unable to use external libraries like Axios, Vutify in the framework Vue front. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put them in the `assets/dependencies folder`. The next time Grunt does a build it will include the script in the layout.ejs file. Do not reference it directly from the layout.ejs file as this is overwritten every time Grunt detects a change.

As far as instantiating any scripts, you will probably want to do that on each page Javascript file `assets/js/pages/{name-of-page}`. Within the beforeMount or mounted lifecycle method. That method is also where you would hydrate your page data:

```
beforeMount: function() {
//Instantiate script here
}
```